# Counting Values in a 2D array - C

Tags: c, xcode, windows, macos, sublimetext3

So I've been trying to work my way through an assignment learning C, and was just hoping for some sort of correction for where i'm going wrong

The scenario is a survey, and this is the output i'm expected to produce

```
     POPULARITY TABLE
     ----------------------------------------------------
     City Cricket Footy Tennis Soccer
     -----------------------------------------------------
     Melbourne 4 1 1 4
     Sydney 4 5 1 0
     Brisbane 2 2 4 4
     Adelaide 1 0 2 0
    -----------------------------------------------------
```

Variables being M, S, B, A and 1,2,3,4 for the table

Everytime I execute my code, it either doesn't count the values or it says theres 36 of one value

```
   #include  <stdio.h>
   int main()
    {
        int  i,  j;
        char M, B, S, A;
        int m_cricket = 0, m_footy = 0, m_tennis = 0, m_soccer = 0;
        int s_cricket = 0, s_footy = 0, s_tennis = 0, s_soccer = 0
        int b_cricket = 0, b_footy = 0, b_tennis = 0, b_soccer = 0
        int a_cricket = 0, a_footy = 0, a_tennis = 0, a_soccer = 0
        int survey[36][2] = {{M, 1}, {S, 2}, {B, 1}, {B, 3}, {M, 2}, {B, 4}, {S, 1}, {A, 3}, {M, 4}, {B, 2}, {B, 1}, {S, 3}, {B, 4}, {B, 4}, {M, 1}, {M, 1}, {B, 3}, {B, 3}, {S, 1}, {S, 1}, {S, 2}, {M, 4}, {M, 4}, {S, 2}, {A, 1}, {S, 2}, {B, 3}, {M, 1}, {B, 1}, {S, 2}, {A, 3}, {M, 4}, {S, 1}, {B, 2}, {M, 3}, {B, 4}};

for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
{
        for (int j = 0; j == 2; j++)
        {
            if (survey[i][j] == M, 1)
            {
                m_cricket++;
            }
        }

}

    printf("\tCity  Cricket Footy  Tennis  Soccer\n");
    printf("------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Melbourne:\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t\n", m_cricket, m_footy, m_tennis, m_soccer);
    printf("Sydney:\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t\n", s_cricket, s_footy, s_tennis, s_soccer);
    printf("Brisbane:\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t\n", b_cricket, b_footy, b_tennis, b_soccer);
    printf("Adelaide:\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t\n", a_cricket, a_footy, a_tennis, a_soccer);

    return 0;
}
```

Where have I gone wrong? Is there a better way I could code this?

I only coded for Melbourne as when coding this, i was going under the logic that if i could get one city working, the rest would be straightforward

Comment: `int  i,  j;` is redundant, since you declare them again in the loops, and they are only used in the loops.

Comment: When doing C programming, you can't just "guess the syntax" through trial and error. That will never work out. Instead, you must actually know what you are doing, at each and every line of code you write. This code doesn't make any sense - you need to study strings and characters in your beginner-level programming book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop...

```
for (int j = 0; j == 2; j++)
```

...does nothing. It only runs whilst `j` is `2`. Since it's initialised to `0` that is never the case, so the code within will never be executed.

If you want it to loop over the values of the inner array (`0` and `1`) you want to check if `j` is less than `2` like this, just like you've done with your outer loop.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
```

Although given you appear to be trying to check both values at the same time in the `if` within those loops, maybe what you want to do is replace that loop with a different `if` statement like this?

```
if ((survey[i][0] == M) && (survey[i][1]== 1))
```

Also if you're intention with the `M`, `B`, `S` and `A` variables is to put in characters into your array you just need to put single quotes around like `'M'` as currently they aren't assigned a value so will potentially have any value. Same would also apply to the `if` statement too.

So to summarise your code should look like this:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
int main()
   {
   int m_cricket = 0, m_footy = 0, m_tennis = 0, m_soccer = 0;
   int s_cricket = 0, s_footy = 0, s_tennis = 0, s_soccer = 0
   int b_cricket = 0, b_footy = 0, b_tennis = 0, b_soccer = 0
   int a_cricket = 0, a_footy = 0, a_tennis = 0, a_soccer = 0
   int survey[36][2] = {{'M', 1}, {'S', 2}, {'B', 1}, {'B', 3}, {'M', 2}, {'B', 4}, {'S', 1}, {'A', 3}, {'M', 4}, {'B', 2}, {'B', 1}, {'S', 3}, {'B', 4}, {'B', 4}, {'M', 1}, {'M', 1}, {'B', 3}, {'B', 3}, {'S', 1}, {'S', 1}, {'S', 2}, {'M', 4}, {'M', 4}, {'S', 2}, {'A', 1}, {'S', 2}, {'B', 3}, {'M', 1}, {'B', 1}, {'S', 2}, {''A'', 3}, {'M', 4}, {'S', 1}, {'B', 2}, {'M', 3}, {'B', 4}};

   for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
      {
      if ((survey[i][0] == 'M') && (survey[i][1]==1))
         {
         m_cricket++;
         }
      }

    printf("\tCity  Cricket Footy  Tennis  Soccer\n");
    printf("------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Melbourne:\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t\n", m_cricket, m_footy, m_tennis, m_soccer);
    printf("Sydney:\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t\n", s_cricket, s_footy, s_tennis, s_soccer);
    printf("Brisbane:\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t\n", b_cricket, b_footy, b_tennis, b_soccer);
    printf("Adelaide:\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t\n", a_cricket, a_footy, a_tennis, a_soccer);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things stand out:

- You use uninitialized character variables (`M`, `B`, `S` and `A`) like they meant something; this is very confusing.
- This line: `if (survey[i][j] == M, 1)` makes no sense at all. It will always take the `if`, since the comma operator makes the condition equivalent to a single `1`.